# How to refresh github code scanning alerts

Tags: github, github-actions

It would be ideal to refresh github-code-scanning alerts when a branch pr is changed, removing old alerts when they become outdated and avoiding duplicating new alerts.

Following the behavior:

- When a new commit is added: Run on this new commit
- When a force push occurs: Re-run (deleting old alerts) on all commits which changed (or more simply, deleting all alerts and re-running on the entire branch).

Specifically I have a repository with code scanning and some generic PR (https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/testing-git-hooks/pull/1) here given my force push my desired behavior would have been for it to delete the first alert or not generate the second duplicate alert.

Is this possible? Where should I begin looking to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "code scanning alerts", do you mean annotations in a PR? If so, are you asking how to remove PR annotations once changes have been merged on main?

Comment: In repository settings it is under `Code security and analysis > Code scanning`, I'm asking to remove annotations as the PR branch changes (before merging).